# "Direction/Length" Tool not working with Polygons in ArcMap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, arcgis-10.3, cogo

My "Direction/Length" right-click option is not working when trying to draw a polygon.

I start a shape by dropping a single vertex, right-clicking and choosing "Direction/Length".
[image]

I enter in the degrees, minutes, seconds, and length that I need and press Enter.

Nothing happens. I right-click a second time and repeat the process. This time a vertex is drawn where I want it. (Weird, but I go with it)
[image]

I repeat the process again for the next vertex, same thing: Nothing happens on the first try, but the second try it drops a vertex.

Only this time, this new vertex is broken off from the rest of the shape, and any prior vertices are also cut off and made independent points. 

[image]

What is going on here? Each new vertex remains independent and does not form a shape.
[image]

Comment: Does it work if you try to set one and then the other separately?

Comment: @AdamKara If I draw a polygon as usual, without the use of specific directions or lengths, it works just fine. Everything connects and forms a shape as it should.

Comment: Is this happening with all polygons or just this specific feature?

Comment: @AdamKara Good question. I just opened up the same feature class in a different map document and it works fine. I wonder if it's a data frame thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully it was just a stupid mistake.

What happened was I had created a new Map Document to work with this particular polygon feature.

When creating this new map document, I forgot to change the Coordinate system to use Feet as the Map Unit of measurement. So, when I was entering my Direction/Length, it was looking for Decimal Degrees and I was feeding it Feet mumbo-jumbo.

All I had to do was open the Data Frame properties window, click the Coordinate System tab, and select the proper Coordinate system to work with the features I am editing.

Comment: I opened a blank MXD to test it really quick and noticed that when I did direction/length the default for direction was angular. I saw that and was going to suggest checking your units but you solved it anyways!

Comment: @AdamKara Thank you very much for asking the right troubleshooting questions to get me on the right track to being productive again. This is the kind of help I come to this site for. <3